# Drupal 5 Search not working on 404 pages

Tags: php, drupal, search, preprocessor, drupal-5

I have a `<?php print $search_box; ?>` in my page.tpl.php page. On pages that exist, the search works, but on 404 pages, it does not.

I saw some bugs/patches threads over at drupal.org for D6.15, but none of them seem to work according to the thread and they weren't really relevant to D5.x

I have a theory that the because the `<?php print $search_box; ?>` creates a form with an action to itself(a non-existant page), it'll get the 404.

Has anyone run up against this? If so, how did you fix it?

One theory I has was to somehow tap into the form and always make the action="/" (front page) which would always exist.

If this is a good idea, how does one go about tapping into the FormAPI and overwriting the action? Is it a preprocess function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In a [form alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter/5) you can use [`drupal_get_headers()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_get_headers/5) to check if the page being displayed is a 404.
2. If it is a 404, you can in your form alter set the `$form['#action']` attribute in your search form to fx the front page or any other page that you would like to redirect the user to.

I haven't tested this, but it should work.

Comment: This got me in the right path. preprocess_page didn't have  access to the $form, but I was able to search replace the action if the drupal_get_headers is a 404